# Speed of molecules in human cells?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology

What is the average speed of molecules in human cells?
Are there molecules moving much faster than others? What is it due to?

Comment: Speed? Are we talking about rate of diffusion, directional movement by energy expenditure or something else, please clarify.

Comment: And what kind of molecule?